# about running ubuntu on a toshiba tecra 8000

Tags: usb, cd

HI I have been given a collection of toshiba laptops  all minus their hard drive   they are tecra 8000. They are dated, but I like to run dated technology if I can rather than trashing it. I don't know their specifications like ram, etc.

I need an os that will run from their usb or cd drives it would have to be one appropriate to their limited ram and whatever limitations are on this dated machine.

Well does anyone know the limits of this machine.

does anyone know the appropriate kind of operating system that will run on them     cd or usb.

Answer (score 0):

**[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)**, the lightes flavor in the Ubuntu family is perfectly addapted for the resources of the machine, and you might as well subtitute some apps for lighter ones for example: use Midori browser instead of Chromium/Firefox.

**System Requirements**

A Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB of RAM is probably a bottom-line configuration that may yield slow yet usable system with a reduced lubuntu desktop.

http://www.westworldcomputers.com/toshiba_tecra_8000_specs_page.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you find Lubuntu is slow, consider the official spec for hardware is (as per the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu))

> Lubuntu can be installed on a Pentium II or Celeron system with 128 MB
>   of RAM, but such a system would not perform well enough for daily use.
>
> With 256MB - 384MB of RAM, the performance will be better and the
>   system will be more usable.
>
> With 512MB of RAM, you don't need to worry much.
>
> The default "Desktop" installer requires 384-800 MB of RAM (depending
>   on selected options.) If you have problems, please use the ["Alternate" installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO).

And, if using the alternate installer does not work well, then consider a distro that's lighter still, such as [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm).

All of the above will run and install from USB (although PCs of that vintage may not boot from USB). Should the latter be true, then you can install from a LiveCD.